# Mercurial. Delete a branch pushed to repository

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I pushed a branch to the repository that is never going to be used again. How can I delete it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot delete anything on a remote repository. History editing actions do need local acces (e.g. also via web interface like availabe on bitbucket).

If you have local access to the repository, then you can strip the changesets which you do not want anymore. Mind, that it's altering history, thus make a backup before. Also mind, that anyone who pulled those changes and does not strip them locally, too, will bring them back, if that person pushes to that repo.

EDIT to add:
That said, if you make use of phases, have a non-publishing repository as server, and the changes you pushed are of draft phase, then it is possible to simply strip the changes without local access. This is especially useful, if you use the evolve extension.

Comment: Well, I left out that part in the (implicit) assumption that it wasn't active on the remote repo the thread starter asks about; if he used evolve, he'd not ask this question. But I'll amend the answer accordingly